# Spring redirect keeping parameters after POST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.2.4 and I have a simple controller that takes a parameter, set it, and redirects the page. For some reason, it is keeping the param even after redirecting. i.e. The page starts at "/" and ends with "/?globalMessage=hereforever", I have tried clearing the modelMap, but that didn't work. I may be misunderstanding something along the lines. I am also adding the model to postHandle in HandlerInterceptor.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "globalMessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setGlobalMessage(@RequestParam String globalMessage) {
    globalProperties.setProperty("globalMessage", globalMessage);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Here is the jsp code in the front

```
<form method="post" action="/globalMessage">
    <input name="globalMessage" type="text" name="message"/>
    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate what do you mean by "it is keeping the param even after redirecting."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring's redirect view will automatically expose model attributes as URL parameters: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1294. If the `globalMessage` is set in the model somewhere, then this will get appended to the redirect URL.

You can tell Spring not to do this using the `setExposeModelAttributes` method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "globalMessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setGlobalMessage(@RequestParam String globalMessage) {
    globalProperties.setProperty("globalMessage", globalMessage);

    RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("/");
    redirect.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
    return redirect;
}
```

Comment: This is working (didn't work when I tried it before >:( ) I should also add that I am using a HandlerInterceptor which adds a String to the model. Would I need to do this for every redirect request then?

Comment: If you didn't want that attribute adding to the redirect URL, then you'd need to do it for every redirect. Spring does provide mechanisms for finer grained control over which model attributes are added to the redirect URL, such as `RedirectAttributes` - see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6796. Other than that, there are other alternatives such as changing the way the String is stored (perhaps place it in session), or create your own RedirectView by subclassing it - so you could control the attribute filtering.